# how i can break things with Fragments with setRetainInstance(true) and adding them to backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

the docs on setRetainInstance say :

> This can only be used with fragments not in the back stack.

so I started playing with it.

I have one Activity with adds first frag A

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content, new PackageFragment());
ft.commit
```

then from this frag I run a method from parent Activity which adds frag B to backstack

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content, new OrderFragment());
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

then I create log msg from onCreate,onDestroy,onSaveInstanceState,onActivityCreated...etc

I try two versions of this process. Rotating the device on each fragment.

1. default

Everything is as expected. onCreate, onDestroy on fragments fire

1. setRetainInstance(true)

Everything is as expected?. onCreate, onDestroy on fragments dont fire

and all seems to work while fragments are in the backstack.. so why the docs say I shouldnt use it?
What are the scenarios where I might get in trouble?

thanks

Comment: When you press the back button is when you start seeing the difference. So for example if you used setRetainInstance on a detail view fragment that temporarily shows up, pressing back might take you out of the app instead of closing this temporary detail view fragment.

Comment: Thanks Marco, were you able to reproduce this problem? please share if so. I can press back with no problem. I tested several scenarios and always the detail fragment is destroyed properly when I press back while both frags have setRetainInstance(true).

Comment: I take back my comment. I am seeing a similar behavior....

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Updated answer:

> What are the scenarios where I might get in trouble?

When adding a `Fragment` to the back stack and passing a `Bundle` in the `Fragment` from `onSaveInstanceState()` to `onCreateView()` on configuration change. Calling `setRetainInstance(true)` will set the `Bundle` to null on configuration change.

(I'm not sure a developer would actually attempt this since using `setRetainInstance(true)` makes `onSaveInstanceState()` kind of redundant, but I didn't see the behaviour documented in the API docs so I wrote up this answer).

If both `addToBackStack()` and `setRetainInstance(true)` are called, `setRetainInstance()` partly alters the `Fragment` lifecycle method calls and parameter values on configuration changes, compared to calling only `addToBackStack()`.

Specifically, in the test below, looking a differences between calling only `addToBackStack()` and calling `setRetainInstance(true)` as well, and seeing what happens on configuration change:

Calling `addToBackStack()` but not `setRetainInstance(true)`;

- `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` are called.
- a bundle passed from `onSaveInstanceState()` is received as a parameter in `onCreateView()`.

Calling both `addToBackStack()` and `setRetainInstance(true)`:

- `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` are not called. This is metioned in the API docs.
- a bundle passed from `onSaveInstanceState()` is not received in `onCreateView()`. The passed-in `Bundle` is null.

A test with logged method calls and parameters tested for null:

In the `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MyFragment fragment;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        fragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("my_fragment_tag");
    } else {
        fragment = new MyFragment();
        FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        t.addToBackStack(null);//toggle this
        t.add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "my_fragment_tag").commit(); 
    }
}
```

In the `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);//toggle this
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("test", "value");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Test 1: Fragment lifecycle when `addToBackStack()` is called , and `setRetainInstance(true)` is *not* called

- onAttach()
- onCreate()
- onCreateView()
- onActivityCreated()
- onStart()
- onResume()

[Device rotated from portrait to landscape]

- onPause()
- onSaveInstanceState()
- onStop()
- onDestroyView()
- **onDestroy()**
- onDetach()
- onAttach()
- **onCreate()**
- **onCreateView() with bundle param != null**
- onStart()
- onResume()

Test 2 & 3: Fragment lifecycle calls with `setRetainInstance(true)` called, `addToBackStack()` called / not called (same result):

- onAttach()
- onCreateView()
- onActivityCreated()
- onStart()
- onResume()

[Device rotated from portrait to landscape]

- onPause()
- onSaveInstanceState()
- onStop()
- onDestroyView()
- onDetach()
- onAttach()
- **onCreateView() with bundle param == null**
- onStart()
- onResume()

Comment: "whereas adding a Fragment to the backstack results in this lifecycle" -- do you have a reference for this? Looking at the code, I do not see where the call to `onAttach()` is dependent upon whether or not the fragment is to be added to the back stack. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I meant when navigating backwards, not when just adding a Fragment. I've edited the sentence to express more clearly what I meant. This is a reference I used: http://assets.en.oreilly.com/1/event/68/Fragments%20for%20All%20Presentation.pdf. Section 19: "If you call addToBackStack() when removing or replacing a fragment:(...)If the user navigates back, the system invokes onCreateView(), onActivityCreated(), onStart(), and onResume() on the fragment."

Comment: Another reference is Professional Android 4 Application Development by Reto Meier, Figure 4.9 (summary of Fragment lifecycle) "Fragment.onCreateView()(...)Fragment returns to the layout from the backstack".

Comment: The API docs you are quoting are specifically for when the activity is being recreated after a configuration change. More concretely, if the activity has not been recreated, onAttach() is not called when navigating back to a removed fragment stored on the back stack, even if setRetainInstance(true) has been called. When an activity is being recreated with a fragment on the back stack, non-retained fragments will receive onAttach() immediately, whilst retained fragments will receive onAttach() only when they are navigated to again.

Comment: @antonyt Thanks for your insightful comment. I've posted an updated answer.

Comment: @GunnarKarlsson  I see `savedInstanceState != null` even `setRetainedInstance(true)` in `onCreateView()`. May be this behaviour has changed since you last posted. Can anyone confirm?