# Values aren't being saved in savedInstanceState

Tags: android, gridview, logcat, instances

For some reason, the values from the gridView aren't being saved from the Bundle. Nothing is being outputted to the logcat either. Am I getting the values from the gridview properly? It is full of edit texts, so it should be getting the values from there

```
public class RedScorerFragment extends SherlockFragment {

LayoutInflater infl;
GridView mGrid;

int R1C1, R1C2, R1C3;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    infl = inflater;
    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_score_red, container, false);
    mGrid = (GridView) mView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewRed);


    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        R1C1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C1");
        R1C2 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C2");
        R1C3 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C3");

        Log.d("savedd R1C1 ", String.valueOf(R1C1));
        Log.d("savedd R1C2 ", String.valueOf(R1C2));
        Log.d("savedd R1C3 ", String.valueOf(R1C3));
    }


    mGrid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        R1C1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C1", 0);
        R1C2 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C2", 0);
        R1C3 = savedInstanceState.getInt("R1C3", 0);

        Log.v("saved R1C1 ", String.valueOf(R1C1));
        Log.v("saved R1C2 ", String.valueOf(R1C2));
        Log.v("saved R1C3 ", String.valueOf(R1C3));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    //for(int i=0;i<mGrid.getChildCount(); i++)
    Log.e("Saving", mGrid.getChildAt(0).toString());
    Log.e("Saving", mGrid.getChildAt(1).toString());
    Log.e("Saving", mGrid.getChildAt(2).toString());
    savedInstanceState.putInt("R1C1", Integer.valueOf(mGrid.getItemAtPosition(0).toString()) );
    savedInstanceState.putInt("R1C2", Integer.valueOf(mGrid.getItemAtPosition(1).toString()) );
    savedInstanceState.putInt("R1C3", Integer.valueOf(mGrid.getItemAtPosition(2).toString()) );

}

}
```

The logcat

```
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {org.say.upscorer/org.say.upscorer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3348)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3288)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at org.saywatt.scoring.RedScorerFragment.onSaveInstanceState(RedScorerFragment.java:91)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performSaveInstanceState(Fragment.java:1607)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1587)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1655)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:527)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:127)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1036)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1180)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3330)
12-22 23:58:38.736: E/AndroidRuntime(2481):     ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Bundle::get` family of functions take a *tag* or *id* as a parameter. That's how they know what exactly are you asking for. I.e.,

```
// get a String with id "R1C1", note the quotes
R1C1 = savedInstanceState.getString("R1C1");
```

The way you are calling them, which works just by chance since you are dealing with `Strings`, is actually asking for a `String` with an *id* of whatever `R1C1` contains at that time.

But you are putting `ints` on the bundle and expect to extract `Strings`, that's a plain and simple error.

Comment: I updated the code in the post to use ints, and its still displaying in logcat

Comment: @rasen58: You do note that on `onSaveInstanceState` you log one thing yet save another, right?

Comment: I'm getting a null pointer exception when I do mGrid.getItemAtPosition

Comment: @rasen58: Are you certain the exception is thrown when doing `mGrid.getItemAtPosition()` and not in the subsequent `.toString()`?

Comment: I press the home button, and it crashes. i posted the log cat

Comment: I think i know why. It seems that  `Integer.valueOf((String) mGrid.getItemAtPosition(0))` is always returning null

Answer (score 0):

How is the parent `Activity` declared in your manifest? If you are handling config changes, i.e.

```
android:configChanges= whatever
```

your `Activity` and thus your `Fragment` will not be recreated.

Comment: Oh i don't have any config changes
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >

Comment: That's the application declaration. Can you post what you have for Activity?

Comment: `<activity
            android:name="org.say.upscorer.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
           >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably another victim of automatic (un)boxing. I suspect that since `Bundle.putInt()` takes an `int` as the 2nd argument, while you're providing it with a value of `Integer.valueOf()` which returns an `Integer`. It'll be fine if this returned `Integer` isn't `null`, but unboxing will simply fail to convert `null` to an ordinary `int` and result in NPE.

What to do is case-specific really and depends on what your application does. Anyway, make sure `Integer.valueOf()` doesn't return `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting

```
setRetainInstance(true)
```

inside your Fragment or setting it from an Activity:

```
myFragment.setRetainInstance(true):
```

then the Bundle passed from `onSaveInstanceState()` to `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()` will be null, even if you add extras to it in `onSaveInstanceState()`.

See this answer: [how i can break things with Fragments with setRetainInstance(true) and adding them to backstack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420448/how-i-can-break-things-with-fragments-with-setretaininstancetrue-and-adding-th/13773496#13773496)

Comment: I don't have `setRetainInstance(true)` anywhere. Do i need it?

Comment: I mentioned it since it's not compatible with using onSaveInstanceState() in a Fragment and in case you called it somewhere it could cause the problem in you described. If you use onSaveInstanceState to pass a bundle, then don't use setInstanceState(). If you want to know more about what it does, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182180/understanding-fragments-setretaininstanceboolean