# Cannot find DialogFragment with ChildFragmentManager

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, fragmentmanager

In my app I have an AppCompatActivity which has a support fragment. From this fragment I am showing a DialogFragment as follows

```
final MyDialogFragment completeDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(titleString,
                messageString, DialogType.Ok);

completeDialogFragment.setDialogCallBack(new MyDialogFragment.DialogCallBacks() {
        @Override
        public void onPositive() {
             // some code to execute when Ok is pressed
            completeDialogFragment.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNegative() {
            // not relevant
        }
    });

completeDialogFragment.setCancelable(false);
FragmentManager mgr = getChildFragmentManager();
completeDialogFragment.show(mgr, MY_TAG);
```

As you can see I am attaching a listener interface to listen to positive / negative button clicks from the dialog fragment. This listener works as expected but when the device gets rotated, it is not. So I wanted to retain or reset this listener whenever the device is rotated. As many people suggested on stackoverflow, I tried to do it the following way in my fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        FragmentManager mgr = getChildFragmentManager();
        final MyDialogFragment completeDialogFragment = 
                      (MyDialogFragment) mgr.findFragmentByTag(MY_TAG);
        if (completeDialogFragment != null) {
            completeDialogFragment
             .setDialogCallBack(new MyDialogFragment.DialogCallBacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPositive() {
                        // some code to execute when Ok is pressed
                        completeDialogFragment.dismiss();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNegative() {
                        // not relevant
                    }
                });
        }

    }
}
```

In the above code segment I am trying to find the dialog fragment by its tag and reset the listener but the variable `completeDialogFragment` is always null. I tried using `getFragmentManager()` and `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` instead and it identifies the fragment but the dialog disappears from screen after rotation. Why the ChildFragmentManager is unable to identify the DialogFragment? Have anyone faced similar issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have one question?. How you got an instance of getChildFragmentManager() in an Activity. Usually childFragmentManagers are associated with fragments. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am calling getChildFragmentManager from the fragment. As stated in the question, I am calling the DialogFragment from a Fragment

Comment: As stated here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22386954/3035416  , try using getSupportManager(). But I am still confused why it is not reappearing. Will get back to you after working out.

Comment: Thanks. If I use ChildFragmentManager, the DialogFragment retains through rotations but I am not able to set the listener again with ChildFragmentManager's findFragmentByTag() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested, the way I solved it was to use `ChildFragmentManager` and use it in `onCreateView()` instead of `onCreate()`. Strange...