# Correct way to show a DialogFragment at Activity#onResume()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I need to show a `DialogFragment` every time the user enter the `Activity`, so the best callback method would be `onResume()`. Thing is I can't just call `DialogFragment#show()` cause it will throw some `IllegalStateException`, so I did this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(!dialog.isVisible()) {
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "login-dialog");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if(dialog.isVisible()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: LoginDialog{41fac3e0 #0 login-dialog}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same exception and message while trying to keep a DialogFragment visible and working between screen rotations (orientation change). **Are your fragments from the support library?**

In my case, I was using the support library and the call to `dialog.show()` was in the activity's `onCreate()`. What seems to have solved the problem was the workaround presented here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14016339/3577211

Which basically is putting `setRetainInstance(true)` in your DialogFragment's `onCreate()`. The second part, that is, overriding its `onDestroy`, was the only way I have managed to make the DialogFragment not go away during screen rotations (and come back when rotating again), even though they say the latest support library versions took care of that (perhaps I have a mess with the jars in here).

You did not state whether you get the exception always or it works only the first time the activity is created. But what I **guess** is happening is that `dialog.show()` is actually a wrapper for a `getFragmentManager().add()` call, which probably checks whether `setRetainInstance` is `true` for the `dialog` and if it is `false`, the `DialogFragment` instance is added again to the same `FragmentManager` instance, which throws that exception.

Yet another suggestion would be not to use `onResume()` for that; instead use `onCreate()` and `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` with some kind of flag, since that way you can save data across activity cycles (and unless your `dialog` is just a popup constant message, which is very annoying to have every time the user hits `onResume()`, you probably have some data to interact with the user that could be lost in unexpected situations).

Answer (score 0):

change 
!dialog.isVisible()
to
!dialog.isAdded()