# custom alert box in android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

The class below is in a file Test.java and I want to call it from the function of public class Test.
Now i dont know how to access the function to show the `alertdialog`. I mean how to access `onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of the class below , from another method?

the code below is copied from [this source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

```
  class MyCustomDialog extends DialogFragment{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_list_layout, null))
        // Add action buttons
               .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // sign in the user ...
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       MyCustomDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
                   }
               });      
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

I want something like this
[image]

Comment: I'm stuck here. Just don't know how to get access to it

Comment: Not sure abt your question, but http://stackoverflow.com/a/8311800/1777090 might help

Comment: I don't know how to access onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) of class MyCustomDialog so that i can popup a alert box as defined above

Comment: Ok. Refer to this. http://arusahni.net/blog/2012/01/implementing-custom-alert-dialogfragments/ . There is method newInstance() in custom dialogfragment class. So you will be able to use it, I think

Comment: Not clear whats your question can you please post me what do you want to display in the custom dialog.

Comment: thanks but i couldnt help myself

Comment: hi.. you want to create your own layout as alert dialog ?

Comment: yes i want to create my own layout .. i see the documentation but i couldnt help myself how to call it. I have uploaded the image in my question - cropped from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html. Please follow the link ans you will see same image. I want exactly that

Comment: MyCustomDialog custDialog = new MyCustomDialog(); custDialog.show(manager, tag) ;

what to put in 'manager'

Comment: @ itsrajesh4uguys  yes i want ot create my own custom dialogbox

Answer (score 3):

```
MyCustomDialog custDialog = new MyCustomDialog();
custDialog.show(custDialog.getFragmentManager(), "Info");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work `MyCustomDialog custDialog = new MyCustomDialog();
            custDialog.show(manager, tag)`